# Get the height of a web view in iOS 10

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I need to get UIWebView height. in method webViewDidFinishLoad I have

```
CGFloat height1 = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.scrollHeight"] floatValue];
CGFloat height2 = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.offsetHeight"] floatValue];
CGFloat height3 = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.clientHeight"] floatValue];
CGFloat height4 = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.documentElement.clientHeight"] floatValue];
CGFloat height5 = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.documentElement.scrollHeight"] floatValue];
CGFloat height6 = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.documentElement.offsetHeight"] floatValue];

height = MAX(height1, MAX(height2, MAX(height3, MAX(height4, MAX(height5, height6)))));
```

and still all values are smaller then real value 
**I have this problem only in iOS 10**

Comment: webView height or webView content height ?

Answer (score 13):

From Apple forums, your problem seem to have a solution

You can use the javascript func scrollHeight to find what you need.

```
NSString *heightStr = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"];
```

You just need to convert it in a usable float value :

```
CGFloat webViewHeight = [heightStr floatValue];
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP used that one for height1 and got a wrong value and so do I.

Comment: It worked for me! I managed to get the correct value in webViewDidFinishLoad. I was using @"document.height" in earlier versions of iOS. @"document.body.scrollHeight;" is working well in iOs10 in my case.

Comment: It worked and works with older versions, tested with 8.1, 9.3 and 10

Comment: @FrancescaI am getting a problem with iOS 10 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45994641/calculate-uiwebview-content-dynamic-height-using-document-body-scrollheight-r